# how to resolve playstore error code-481

Tags: android

Can someone help me how to overcome playstore error code 481, tried Everything like clearing cache , forcefully stopped the playstore service , cleared data,rebooting the device and login to playstore using new google account . No luck so far

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your storage (remove unused apps, for example) and after try again to download.

Comment: No, remove them at all form device.

Comment: nope, no luck removed 3-4 application but still ,same status :(

Comment: check size of target app and free little bit more size at device